# ReactJS error when I POST to my newest MySQL table

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I have two tables in my Mysql database. When I only had one table everything worked perfectly. I created a new tables, when I run the command "node serve.js" it works and gives no errors.

The new tables is used to manage the info of the logged users. I encounter an error after compiling the form in "UserInfo.js" file when I press the submit button.
[image]

On Postman I get Error and if i type localhost:8080/api/users I get "Cannot GET /api/users
My users controller:

```
const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");

  var router = require("express").Router();

  // Create a new Tutorial
  router.post("/users", users.create);

  // Retrieve all Tutorials
  router.get("/users", users.findAll);


  // Retrieve a single Tutorial with id
  router.get("/users/:id", users.findOne);

  // Update a Tutorial with id
  router.put("/users/:id", users.update);

  // Delete a Tutorial with id
  router.delete("/users/:id", users.delete);


  app.use('/api/users', router); 
};
```

and my models index.js:

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.tutorials = require("./tutorial.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);



module.exports = db;
```

I've already read the answers to similar questions and searched for various tutorials outside of stackoverflow.
I'm learning and started less than 2 months ago so don't tell me to google because I can't solve it by myself.
Thanks for your help.

Resolved. New controller:

```
const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");

  var router = require("express").Router();

  // Create a new Tutorial
  router.post("/", users.create);

  // Retrieve all Tutorials
  router.get("/", users.findAll);


  // Retrieve a single Tutorial with id
  router.get("/:id", users.findOne);

  // Update a Tutorial with id
  router.put("/:id", users.update);

  // Delete a Tutorial with id
  router.delete("/:id", users.delete);


  app.use('/api/users', router); 
};
```

New models index.js:

```
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle
  }
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.tutorials = require("./tutorial.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.users= require("./user.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize)


module.exports = db;
```

Comment: can you post the code for the route? the error in your screenshot is 404 not found

Comment: @azium Is everything already in codesandbox, or maybe I don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I investigated that the backend source but I've found that you misunderstand how to define route.

```
 const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");

  var router = require("express").Router();

  // Create a new Tutorial
  router.post("/users", users.create);

  // Retrieve all Tutorials
  router.get("/users", users.findAll);


  // Retrieve a single Tutorial with id
  router.get("/users/:id", users.findOne);

  // Update a Tutorial with id
  router.put("/users/:id", users.update);

  // Delete a Tutorial with id
  router.delete("/users/:id", users.delete);


  app.use('/api/users', router); 
};
```

It's the backend source you defined but you are using app.use to define route so you can call the endpoints by /api/users/[sub-url] like this

endpoint: localhost:8080/api/users/users
method: POST

If you wanna use the endpoints like localhost:8080/api/users then you should define the backend routes like this.

```
const users = require("../controllers/user.controller.js");

  var router = require("express").Router();

  // Create a new Tutorial
  router.post("/", users.create);

  // Retrieve all Tutorials
  router.get("/", users.findAll);


  // Retrieve a single Tutorial with id
  router.get("/:id", users.findOne);

  // Update a Tutorial with id
  router.put("/:id", users.update);

  // Delete a Tutorial with id
  router.delete("/:id", users.delete);


  app.use('/api/users', router); 
};
```

I hope this can be helpful for you.
Regards.

Comment: Yes, with Postman I get Error and if i type localhost:8080/api/users I get "Cannot GET /api/users". Since the type of information as well as the form to be filled are identical I used the same code. I don't understand why it works for tutorials and for userinfo it doesn't.

Comment: the endpoint is located at the url localhost.8080 / api / users. I don't understand how I can share it ... or maybe I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Did you run the backend server on 8080?

Comment: I changed my answer, so you can review it. Let me know if you have problems on my answer.

Comment: Now I get "500 Internal Service Error" TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined.  Create is located in "user.controller.js" line 30.

Comment: You should add db.users= require("./users.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
in model/index.js after tutorials model definition

Comment: Great to hear @G